# How to make search filter for each column in html table in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a HTML table which I made from scratch and rendering it with APIs data, I did all the pagination sorting and other stuffs but now I am trying to do search filter for each column.

I made one global search filter which works totally fine but facing issue with the making search for each column.

**What I am doing**

- Below is my HTML table component

  ```
           <HTMLTable
             tableData={tData} // here passing data as tData
             tableClass="table"
             theadClass="theadClass"
             tbodyClass="tbodyClass"
           />
  ```
- What I am doing is getting data from api and creating one state and updating it in useEffect when page loads as empty array dependency like below

  ```
   const [searchData, setsearchData] = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
   setsearchData(data); // here updating my state with the api data
   }, []);
  ```
- Now below is my logic I am using to filter the data

  ```
  const table_data =
   searchData &&
   searchData.filter((item) => {
   return (
   item[context.columnTypedInto] // here whichever column user types I am passing it as 
   context
     ?.toString() // writing the logic for number
     .toLowerCase()
     .includes(context.SearchValue.toLowerCase()) || // when user types anything I am 
     saving it in context and passing it here
    !context.SearchValue
     );
  });
  ```
- So About the above code, i have created a context when user types in any of the column I know which column they are typing into so that is `context.columnTypedInto` and what user is typing that too I am storing into a context which is `context.SearchValue` so this works fine
- Now What i am trying to do is when user is typing anything I am getting that related data and updating my state `setsearchData` which works fine, below is the code

  ```
   useEffect(() => {
   setsearchData(table_data);
  }, [context.SearchValue]);
  ```

SO whenever search value changes this code will run and it is working fine if I type in any column and search then I type in another column it search for the first searched data only not the whole data.

**Issue I am facing**

What issue I am facing is, whenever I am press backspace it won't work because the latest data in state is what I typed the last, so when I presss backspace I want it to take the previous data and when nothing is there the whole data should show.

That is the only part I am left with, I hope I have explained it well, if not, I will take the inputs and explain my issue again.

**Edit/Update**

I tried the below answer updated by @jantimon but that is not working, [here is my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-johnson-l86eei?file=/src/App.js)

**Below I am explaining the full scenario**

- When I type in first_name column lets say I typed `Jeanette` so below is the data for this
- `1   Jeanette    Penddreth   jpenddreth0@census.gov  Female  26.58.193.2`
- Now If I type `Giavani` in first_name column it should show empty table because now the data is just one row, and when I press backspace it retain the data step-by-step
- Before this edit When I type in firstname and then search for other it shows empty table which is totally fine but when I press backspace it is not taking the last data.

I have updated the `codeSand box` please do check.

i am trying [to implement like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table2-clear-search-bar-and-filter-czbhy6)

Comment: By the way, have you tried ready libraries for tables instead of implementing a wheel, for example @tanstack/react-table? It is headless and is batteries-included - it has pagination, filters, etc

Comment: @VladVladov I know about those, but I want o do it through scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if understand the problem correctly you want to find the rows that match all the column filters.

(I will ignore the global search in this answer because you said that you know how to make it work and because you don't have it in the UI of your sandbox)

to do that you have to save a search text per column, for example, in a map from column name to search text.
in your code, it seems that you have a single column name and a single search text which gets overridden each time.

so when a user types something we will call the onChange function with both column and value - `context.OnChangeFeildTyped({ column: li, value });`
And in the reducer, we will add this value to the filters map (or remove it if the value is empty)

```
case "ONCHNAGESEARCHSELECT":
      let newColumnTypedInto;
      if (action.payload.value.length > 0) {
        newColumnTypedInto = {
          ...state.columnTypedInto,
          [action.payload.column]: action.payload.value
        };
      } else {
        newColumnTypedInto = { ...state.columnTypedInto };
        delete newColumnTypedInto[action.payload.column];
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        columnTypedInto: newColumnTypedInto
      };
```

The last thing we need to do is to filter items that match all column filters

```
const filteredtableData = useMemo(() => {
    if (!tableData) return [];
    // filter the column by searchText
    return tableData.filter((item) => {
      const columnsToFilterBy = Object.keys(context.columnTypedInto);
      return columnsToFilterBy.every((column) =>
        item[column]
          ?.toString() // writing the logic for number
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(context.columnTypedInto[column])
      );
    });
  }, [context.columnTypedInto]);
```

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-voice-t8gbk0?file=/src/WelcomePage.js:874-1348) is a sandbox with your code + my fixes

** On an unrelated note, it is better to set `key` to the id of a row and not its index. because then if you apply a filter and the row moved from being 3rd to being 2nd react will know that it's the same row.